# Ошибка при подключении к какому-либо из Bluetooth серверов

Tags: python, python-2.7

Скажите пожалуйста почему при запуске кода у меня выскакивает ошибка?
Вот код:

```
import bluetooth

bd_addr = "00:03:b9:b3:c1:38"

port = 1

sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))

sock.send("hello!!")

sock.close()
```

А вот сама ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Рабочий стол\парпар.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       sock.connect((bd_addr, port))   File "D:\2012\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 72, in connect
>       bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port) OSError

У меня блютуз адаптер работает и все у него в норме. Подскажите, как мне исправить данную ошибку?

---

Короче говоря я попробовал изменить версию питона на более старую 2.7 и увидел,что ошибки по крайней мере хотя бы, что-то поясняют в отличие от прошлого раза.

Вот мой код,который я запустил и в котором у меня выдался результат, а так же ошибка.

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
port = 0
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)
server=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server.connect(('00:11:22:98:76:54',PORT_ANY))

server.send("hello!!")

server.close()

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
server.close()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Рабочий стол\fhg.py", line 9, in  sock.connect((bd_addr, PORT_ANY)) File
>   "D:\pythonchik\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 72, in
>   connect bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port) IOError: Требуемый адрес
>   для своего контекста неверен.

Answer (score 1):

Тяжело было найти эту библиотеку, оставили бы ссылку на неё. Попробуйте подключиться по другому протоколу и порту:

```
from bluetooth import *

port = 0xFA0 # 4000
sock = BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)
bt_addr = input('Введите адрес устройства: ')

print("Попытка соединения с устройством %s" % bt_addr)

try:
    sock.connect((bt_addr, port))
    print("Соединение успешно")
except:
    print('Connection error')

while True:
    data = input()
    if(len(data) == 0):
        break

    sock.send(data)
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print("Получено: ", data)
```

**UPD**

Поиск устройств:

```
from bluetooth.ble import DiscoveryService

service = DiscoveryService()
devices = service.discover(2)

for address, name in devices.items():
    print("name: {}, address: {}".format(name, address))
```

Comment: Я узнал,что L2CAP не поддерживается почему-то на python 2 или python 3 для windows 7.Вот ссылка на тему:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460076/pyblues-bluetooth-l2cap И в частности это не избежало и меня(у меня высвечивается та же ошибка,что и фигурирует в теме по ссылке).И кстати:модуль называется pybluez.Вот ссылка на него:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBluez.И скажите мне пожалуйста,есть ли другие варианты решения,но с RFCOMM для исправления данной ошибки?

Comment: @Киря005 к сожалению, я не могу вам точно подсказать решение. У меня нет возможности протестировать код. Единственное устройство с bluetooth у меня это нетбук, но на нём стоит Linux. Я думаю, что вам стоит попробовать переустановить устройство, либо проверить его настройки в панели управления и попробовать хотя бы поискать устройства поблизости: в ответе (обновлю сейчас, взято из документации)